# fan running loudly nonstop on lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

The fan keeps running on my dell laptop (Lubuntu 14.04) although hardly anything really is running, "top" shows 95% idle cpu.  If I reboot, the fan will be silent, but starts running again after several days of being on.

Not sure what triggers the fan to start running even when top shows nothing.

Isn't there a utility to turn off the fan?

Comment: You should not turn the fan off. It seems like it might have a hardware error. Have you considered replacing the fan (running loudly)?   Less likely (I think), fan circuit may have developed an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

I.

> "top" shows 95% idle cpu.

If there is a physical problem with airflow then your CPU could be 100% idle yet the fans would be running - there are components other than the CPU that generate heat.  Dust out all vents with canned air (carefully) and if the issue still persists open the laptop and dust further or take it to a professional who can do that for you.  If your laptop is old and from an OEM manufacturer such as Dell, HP, etc. reapplying the thermal paste may also help.

II. Does it sound like the fan is running at top speed?  Most fans will default to full speed if nothing is telling them to slow down (safest option for failure).  A device in your laptop called an Embedded Controller (EC) continually monitors temperature sensors and updates the fan speed.  If it crashes, stops working, or doesn't like how it's talked to by the OS, then the fan might "panic."  If you flashed your laptop with a custom UEFI/BIOS, check for an update or see if this is a known/discovered issue.  Otherwise you could try a UEFI/BIOS update from the manufacturer.

Other things that might involve the internal EC are the battery, Thunderbolt/USB 4.0 controllers, and entering/leaving sleep mode.

III. Most laptop manufacturers make and certify their laptops for Windows - at least until recently.  Fixes on Linux for specific BIOS/UEFI bugs or quirks that are discovered when Windows is not in the loop are not uncommon.  Depending on your laptop make/model it may be something known and fixed in the future.

IV. `lm-sensors` appears to optionally have a utility called `fancontrol` (I've never tried it but have used `lm-sensors` before) which might help in controlling it.  `lm-sensors` can also tell you how hot the sensors think that the temperature is.